# Rails - Acts_as_versioned ------ save_without_revision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using acts_as_versioned for images. Though it's possible in my app to update just the title, which shouldn't be a version as version are for image replacements.

Problem is, if you update just the title, acts_as_versioned creates a new version which breaks everything. So when calling the model def update_title for photos, I want to try what I found in the DOC:

save_without_revision: http://ar-versioned.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/Versioned/ActMethods.html#M000008

But I don't know how to do that? Where do I include this? Somewhere, somehow in the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it like regular active record, in your controller. eg:

```
@article.save_without_revision
```

I recommend you use [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions) anyhow.